# Upgrading Cocos2d version from 0.99 to 3.1

Tags: iphone, ios7, cocos2d-iphone, 2d-games

I am new to developing games with Cocos2d and trying to find out a solution for a simple problem (but the solution seems to be a complex one).
My app has been rejected by Apple because it wasn't supporting 4 inch iPhone display. The app currently is developed using Cocos2d version 0.99. Now I want to upgrade it to a greater version so that I can handle 4 inch display. I cannot find a proper way to migrate from an older version to new one. The only thing I want to achieve is to handle 4 inch display. Is it possible with the older version? or it is necessary to upgrade. If there is a way, how should I achieve it?

Comment: If you get no good answers on this site, then I would recommend asking here: http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org/

Comment: The basic process still applies: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/05/update-cocos2d-iphone-existing-project/  Expect a ton of changes to be made to adapt your code to the new cocos2d v3 API. You may want to go with v2.x instead, there'll be far fewer changes to make and particularly the behavioral changes are fewer.

Comment: Ok, I have decided to go with a earlier version i.e. 2.1 but according to your tutorial some folders and files are still not available in 2.1 either. How do I solve the missing files? Such as b2TOISolver or Linejoint?